# arc of angle and arc of reference angle python

Tags: python

I am trying to draw an arc inside of a circle that I have made.  I want a curved line and I want to label the arc 5*pi/6.  For the math symbols in the label I can use LaTex, but I am having a hardest time with the arc inside the circle. here is my code so far.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as syp

# This is for the unit circle
angle = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 150)
radius = 1
x = radius *np.cos(angle)
y = radius * np.sin(angle)

figure, axes = plt.subplots(1)
# Seting up axes to show so I can type info about reference angles
plt.ylim(-1,4)
plt.xlim(-1,4)
axes.plot(x,y)
plt.plot([-1,1], [0,0])
plt.plot([0,0], [-1,1],color="red")
plt.plot([-syp.sqrt(3)/2,0],[1/2,0],"green")
axes.set_aspect(1)

# draw an arc from initial side of angle to the terminal side at (sqrt3/2,1/2)


plt.title('Reference Angles')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit "low tech", but how I achieved drawing an arc onto your plot was to just draw a portion of another circle that had a slightly smaller radius.  Following is the additions I made to your example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as syp
import math     # Added this for the "arcsin" function

# This is for the unit circle
angle = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 200)
radius = 1
x = radius *np.cos(angle)
y = radius * np.sin(angle)

figure, axes = plt.subplots(1)
# Seting up axes to show so I can type info about reference angles
plt.ylim(-1,4)
plt.xlim(-1,4)
axes.plot(x,y)
# Stuff I added to draw a portion of a circle so that it looks like an arc
angll = np.arcsin((1/2) / (math.sqrt(3) / 2)) * .8
anglex = np.linspace((np.pi - angll), np.pi, 200)
radiusx = .8
xx = radiusx *np.cos(anglex)
yy = radiusx * np.sin(anglex)
axes.plot(xx,yy)
# End of stuff I added
plt.plot([-1,1], [0,0])
plt.plot([0,0], [-1,1],color="red")
plt.plot([-syp.sqrt(3)/2,0],[1/2,0],"green")
axes.set_aspect(1)

# draw an arc from initial side of angle to the terminal side at (sqrt3/2,1/2)

plt.title('Reference Angles')
plt.show()
```

Following is a sample of the plot diagram.

[image: Plot Example]

Hopefully, I captured the gist of what you wanted to do.  By no means is this a brilliant solution, but I think is does what you are after.

Regards.

Comment: Hi, thanks.. this works great.  I am taking a precalculus course.  I have a terrible memory so i am trying to make notes with diagrams.   This is just the easier of the programs that I have found that makes diagrams and stuff.  Someday I hope to break into the IT field but I have along way to go.  So I really appreciate it.  thank you.

Comment: Best of luck to you in your pursuit of I.T.  I was in I.T. for forty years as an I.T. manager and programmer/analyst.  But now I am nicely retired.

Comment: That sounds like a great career.  I work for a finically consultant and I work from home.  I’d like to study computation finance or business intelligence. I need more math in my background and I need to be able to program.  It is an aspiration right now that I have been thinking about so it may not ever happen.  It will take some determination.